# What technology should I use for tracking small boats venturing upto 50km in the sea?

Tags: communication, lora

2017 south India was struck by a cyclone Okhi which took many small fishermen's life. I'm an electrical engineering student and want to do a project regarding tracking these boats and implement an emergency beacon system. Current I'm considering LoRa but I'm highly sceptical about it's range. What are the other cost effective options to track a boat within 50km from the shore. I'm aware of the EPIRB but that thing is costly and I cost is a primary concern for me. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's well beyond the horizon unless you have a mountain handy.  What you have is as much a social/regulatory problem as an engineering one.

Comment: See [AIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system). I think it is a standard way of tracking.

Comment: AIS, as AJN says, which has a claimed range of 70+km and it's possible to track AIS via satellite if the range is not sufficient.

Comment: AIS is in the marine VHF range (162MHz to be precise) and,like marine VHF, has a range that's very dependent upon the height above sea level of both the receiver and the transmitter. 70+ km is very optimistic and will not be reached in most cases.35-40km is more realistic. AIS Class B as licensed to leisure boats is limited to 2W of transmitting power, which will further reduce range. Class A (for commercial use) can transmit up to 12.5W. EPIRBs can not be used for tracking and are exclusively used in emergencies.

Comment: That said, AIS via satellite might be a better option and is becoming more affordable. There are already many well developed technologies for tracking ships, so I would not recommend developing your own.

Comment: There are LEO satellite services that operate in the VHF range for applications just like this. I once worked on a product that provided, among other things, a geo-fencing function so that boat rental operators could verify that the customer remained within the agreed-upon zone. It provided telemetry of key boat functions in addition to GPS location, including a panic switch for emergencies.